# Upgrading ASP.Net skills

Tags: asp.net

I've been a ASP.Net developer since the 1.0/1.1 days.  While I've tried to keep up, I'm sure there are several features and improvements I've missed through the years.  Does anyone know of a concise list of major improvements they've made to the framework through the years?

Comment: Too many to list..which version are you working on now? Please don't say 1.1

Comment: I'm on 4.0.  I'd kill myself if I was still stuck on 1.1.  I'm sure I still have a very 1.1 way of doing a lot of the things I'm doing.  I've looked at ASP.Net MVC, but its not a good fit for a lot of the things I have to do in my day job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the "ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 Web Development Overview" from Microsoft:

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4

I was looking for something similar and this was the best resource I could find :-)